# Connection action on derivative of metric tensor

Tags: tensors, general-relativity

Let $\nabla$ be levi civita connection on Riemannian manifold $M$. I was wondering, what is $\nabla_{\alpha}(\partial_{\beta}g_{\mu\nu})$?

Is it $\partial_{\alpha}\partial_{\beta}g_{\mu \nu}-\Gamma^{\sigma}_{\alpha \beta}\partial_{\sigma}g_{\mu\nu}-\Gamma^{\sigma}_{\alpha \nu}\partial_{\beta}g_{\sigma \nu}-\Gamma^{\sigma}_{\alpha \nu}\partial_{\beta}g_{\mu \sigma}$?

Answer (score 0):

Some hints.

Recall the definition of covariant derivative:

$$\nabla_{\mu}g_{\alpha\beta} \equiv \dfrac{\partial g_{\alpha\beta}}{\partial x^{\mu}} - \Gamma^{\eta}_{\mu\alpha}g_{\eta\beta} - \Gamma^{\gamma}_{\mu\beta}g_{\alpha\gamma}$$

As well as the definition of Christoffel Symbols

$$\Gamma^{\ell}_{ij} \equiv \dfrac{1}{2}g^{\ell k}\left(\dfrac{\partial g_{\ell i}}{\partial x^{j}} + \dfrac{\partial g_{\ell j}}{\partial x^{i}} - \dfrac{\partial g_{ij}}{\partial x^{\ell}}\right)$$

Can you then manage to derive the form of $\nabla_a(\partial_{\beta} g_{\mu\nu})$?

Comment: That's what I tried doing.

Comment: Then it's ok, you first compute $\partial_{\beta}g$ and then act with $\nabla_a$. It's perhaps long but funny!

Comment: what does $T^{\sigma}_{\beta}g_{\sigma \mu}$ evaluate to? $T_{\beta \mu}$?

Comment: By the contraction of a tensor with the metrics, you indeed have $T^{\alpha}_{\beta} g_{\alpha \mu} = T_{\beta\mu}$

Comment: In general, $T^{\alpha}_{\beta}g_{\alpha \mu}\neq g_{\alpha \mu}T^{\alpha}_{\beta}$?

Comment: @monoidaltransform Yes, because you can imagine them as matrices, and generally they do not commute.